# How does SSH key validation work in the continuous integration context of Github workflow?

Tags: git, github, ssh, github-actions, ssh-keys

The usage of SSH keys in a continous integration context such as Github workflow actions to clone and push to a Github repo raises questions for me.

Normally the key validation happens interactively with a manual check of the fingerprint.
I do `git clone ssh://git@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git`.
Then it says:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Then I should not say yes blindly but rather check the fingerprint against the one published by Github here:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints

These are GitHub's public key fingerprints:

- SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 (RSA)
- SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM (ECDSA)
- SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU (Ed25519)

Then I see that the fingerprints match and I can accept. This should help stay safe from man-in-the-middle attacks.

I started with an empty `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file but as soon as I accepted, 3 entries for "github.com" came up into the file, one for each algorithm (RSA, ECDSA, Ed25519)

So now it means that I'm all set to make some automated git-pushes with the maven release plugin, for example.

But that raises the question of how do I put in place the automated check of fingerprint above in the continuous integration context of the Github workflow.

If I look at this plugin https://github.com/actions/checkout, it enables for a SSH key to be provided at checkout time (i.e. git clone)

```
# SSH key used to fetch the repository. The SSH key is configured with the local
# git config, which enables your scripts to run authenticated git commands. The
# post-job step removes the SSH key.
#
# We recommend using a service account with the least permissions necessary.
#
# [Learn more about creating and using encrypted secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets)
ssh-key: ''
```

What key should be put here ? public or private ? it's confusing for me.

EDIT :

The context is the automation of the release process with the maven release plugin in the Github actions workflow. The maven release plugin pushes the tag of the release, and pushes the next development version. Therefore it needs to authenticated to perform the git pushes.
There's this plugin that I'm already using `qcastel/github-actions-maven-release@master` but here I'm focusing on 2 different approaches:

- 1 with a plain SSH style git clone which works well once the initial question on the fingerprint is answered, the known_hosts file is populated, and the git pushes done by the maven release plugin work based on the private key given in the settings file. Only the first manual step causes an automation issue that also raises security issues. Therefore I keep the known_hosts in a repository secret named KNOWN_HOSTS.

  ```
    runs-on: windows-latest
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[maven-release-plugin]')"

    steps:
    - name: Create .ssh directory
      run: md C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh
    - name: Create known hosts file
      run: echo "${{ secrets.KNOWN_HOSTS }}" > C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh\known_hosts
    - name: Create private key
      run: echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh\id_ed25519
    - name: Convert to UNIX format
      run: |
        dos2unix C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh\known_hosts
        dos2unix C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh\id_ed25519
    - name: SSH Git clone
      run: git clone ssh://git@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Create maven settings
      uses: s4u/maven-settings-action@v2.5.0
      with:
        servers: '[{"id": "github.com", "username": "git", "privateKey": "C:/Users/runneradmin/.ssh/id_ed25519"}]'
    - name: Git Config
      run: |
        git config --global user.email "git@github.com"
        git config --global user.name "git"
    - name: Release with Maven
      run: |
        cd myrepo
        mvn -B -Dusername=git release:clean release:prepare release:perform
  ```

This approach is tested and works fine.

- 1 other with the checkout actions where it's possible to provide ssh-key and known_hosts information as parameter.

  ```
    runs-on: windows-latest
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[maven-release-plugin]')"

    steps:
    - name: Create .ssh directory
      run: md C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh
    - name: Create private key
      run: echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh\id_ed25519
    - name: Convert to UNIX format
      run: dos2unix C:\Users\runneradmin\.ssh\id_ed25519
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        ssh-key: "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}"
        ssh-known-hosts: "${{ secrets.KNOWN_HOSTS }}"
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Create maven settings
      uses: s4u/maven-settings-action@v2.5.0
      with:
        servers: '[{"id": "github.com", "username": "git", "privateKey": "C:/Users/runneradmin/.ssh/id_ed25519"}]'
    - name: Git Config
      run: |
        git config --global user.email "git@github.com"
        git config --global user.name "git"
    - name: Release with Maven
      run: mvn -B -Dusername=git release:clean release:prepare release:perform
  ```

Here's the error when I use this approach:

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M5:perform (default-cli) on project jd-gui-duo-parent: Unable to checkout from SCM
Error:  Provider message:
Error:  The git-clone command failed.
Error:  Command output:
Error:  Cloning into 'checkout'...
Error:  Host key verification failed.
Error:  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Here's the content of KNOWN_HOSTS:

```
github.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOMqqnkVzrm0SdG6UOoqKLsabgH5C9okWi0dh2l9GKJl
github.com ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==
github.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEmKSENjQEezOmxkZMy7opKgwFB9nkt5YRrYMjNuG5N87uRgg6CLrbo5wAdT/y6v0mKV0U2w0WZ2YB/++Tpockg=
```

The contents are automatically generated as soon as accept the fingerprint after a SSH-style git clone `git clone ssh://git@github.com/myusername/myrepo.git`

Comment: You're confusing SSH **host key** of the host `github.com` and SSH **user key** of the user `github.com/myusername`.

Comment: what do you mean, yes github.com has its public key, just like I have public key for my repo, and also a private key, then?

Comment: You've asked "*…how do I put in place the automated check of fingerprint above…*" and then showed config for `checkout` action. The first question is about Github **host key**, a key to connect to the host; you cannot put a private key as you don't have it; it's at Github. The second config is about **your user key**, a key to fetch the repository; a completely different key.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough. I will clarify where my questions come from